# Knowing when to create an instance of class over creating a subclass?

Tags: python, oop

I'm in the process of adding items to a text-based RPG I'm making.  My classes look like this:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, description):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.description = description

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, value, damage, description):
        self.damage = damage
        super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, value, description)
```

My player's inventory is a dictionary with keys representing different in-game item groups:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, inventory, ...):
        self.inventory = {'weapons': []}
hero = Player()
```

The question is, when viewing tutorials, they have me make a class of an item as so:

```
class Dagger(Weapon):
    def __init__(...)
        ...
```

And add it to my inventory `hero.inventory['weapons'].append(Dagger())`

My question being: is there any benefit to creating new sub-classes like `Dagger()` over just creating instances of the `Weapon()` class, since I have no additional attributes to add to individual weapons?

Thanks for any help, I hope this post is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use subclass when there is natural is-a relationship.

**Don't use inheritance just to get code reuse**

**Don't use inheritance just to get polymorphism**

In your example case Dagger is a Weapon, so it makes perfect sense to use sub class.

You can get good reading material if you search for inheritance vs composition, or is-a vs has-a

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In terms of code style, creating subclasses is better because it allows for a more dynamic code base so you can expand on it further. In addition, it makes your code more readable, and you can also add help messages/info text more easily. However, if, as you said, you only need to store the damage, there is not much of an advantage to creating subclasses; do keep in mind you also want to store the name of the weapon. I would advise you to create subclasses, because it allows for further development and is better for your code style.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on if you want to add different variables to the newly created subclass. The danger will take on the weapon class with the name, value, damage, and description. I would have my different weapons have subclasses like longsword, sword, dagger, staff, etc. These would be for the different types of weapons the would have different attack types. Dagger may only have jab/stab while longsword would have slash, jab, and maybe some kind of power slash.